# Amazon Rekognition Object detection

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-rekognition

I am beginning to insert myself in the world of AWS, specifically in Amazon Rekognition. I can't find any example on how to use it. So, is there an example made in android studio, on how to use Amazon Rekognition, to detect objects in an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many examples of how to use Amazon Rekognition with the AWS SDK for Java V2. Here are the Java V2 standalone Amazon Rekognition examples:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/rekognition/src/main/java/com/example/rekognition

***If you have never used the AWS SDK for Java V2, please refer to this topic in the DEV Guide that shows you how to get up and running:***

[Get started with the AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html)

Here are some examples of how to use Amazon Rekognition with the Java API (V2) to perform various use cases - such as locating objects like PPE gear within given images. Some show use within a Lambda function and others show use within a web app:

[Creating an Amazon Web Services Lambda function that tags digital assets located in Amazon S3 buckets](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_lambda_tag_assets)

[Creating an example AWS photo analyzer application using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_app)

[Creating AWS video analyzer applications using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/video_analyzer_application)

[Creating an AWS Lambda function that detects images with Personal Protective Equipment](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_lambda_ppe)

Just a tip - when looking for AWS SDK Code examples in a supported programming language, please refer to:

[Finding code examples](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples)

Comment: Thank you, I will check it!